# Call jquery ajax "POST" with crossdomain jsonp from C# ASP.NET asmx

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, cross-domain, jsonp

```
$.ajax({type: "post",
            url: "http://test.com/Register",
            data: {
            "UserID": '12',
            "FirstName": 'FN1'
            },

            accept: {
                json: "application/json",
                jsonp: "application/javascript"
            },
            dataType: "jsonp",
            crossDomain: true,
            beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                xhr.withCredentials = true;
            },
            xhrFields: {
                withCredentials: true
            },
            cache: false,
            success: function (data) {
                if(data.success)
        {
            alert("success");
        }
        else
        {
            alert("failed");
        }   
            }
});
```

I have this Ajax call working with javascript.
But I'm trying to make this same call through C#, using HTTPWebRequest and am not getting the same results.
When I do the call through C# it returns a webpage, instead of a json string,which is not right. And that is happening because the call for some reason is not proper.
But the AJAX call return a proper json string back to me.
I think it is because the ajax call specifies the datatype as "jsonp" and specifies it is cross domain.

The reason I need this to work in C# is because I want this C# call to be made inside a web service.
So a form calls my web service(MyWebservice.asmx), which inturn makes this call in question to http://test.com/Register.
So I cant really have AJAX / Jquery written into my webservice, and would rather have to use C# to make this call.

Any help?

```
    string data = "[SOME JSON DATA]";
    byte[] bytesArray = encoding.GetBytes(data);
            HttpWebRequest httpRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://test.com/Register");


            httpRequest.Method = "POST";
            httpRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            httpRequest.ContentLength = bytesArray.Length;
            using (Stream stream = httpRequest.GetRequestStream())
            {
                stream.Write(bytesArray, 0, bytesArray.Length);
                stream.Close();
            }

            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)httpRequest.GetResponse();

            Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream);
            // Read the response content.
            responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd(); //This gives an HTML page as response
```

Comment: JSONP can't be POST for the same reason you can't POST using a script tag or an image element. `<script src="http://test.com/Register?callback=jQuery61984769182746916529178256931"></script>`

Comment: Kevin, do you mean it is not possible to do the same POST using C#?

Comment: I'm disputing this claim: *"I have this Ajax call working with javascript."* if it's working, it either isn't POST, or it isn't JSONP. If you're making the request using C#, you don't need JSONP anyway, you simply need to perform a basic http request to get the string response, then parse the string response.

Comment: C# doesn't have to abide by the same origin policy, therefore the fact that it is cross-domain is irrelevant.

Comment: Kevin, I think you are right. when I check the fiddler for the ajax call, it says GET even though the jquery code says POST. And does the HTTPWebRequest, that I'm trying, look suspect at all?. Maybe I'm missing something, and hence the wrong response.

Comment: well, i've never written a single line of C#, so i'd have to go to the documentation to have any clue on that

Answer (score 1):

Kevin B's reply helped. Like he mentioned JsonP posts are no different, and is plain old HttpWebRequest call. In this case it was a 'GET' for me.
Here the response I was expecting was pure json, and the service I was calling was returning JsonP (json with padding), hence end point on my side was throwing up. 
Took care of the padding in JsonP and it was all good to go.
Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try setting **content type** to `@"application/json; charset=utf-8"`? I would also suggest using **JavaScriptSerializer** to construct the JSON string.